# Sorting list for most efficient build

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have a problem that I am having some trouble tackling, I am playing this game and thought it would be fun to make a calculator to calculate the most efficient builds.

Every fleet allows for 30 units, and a fleets power is the sum of every units power combined.

Every unit can give a certain amount of power ranging from 1  to 200. The price of these units is different and can vary from unit to unit,  (A 200 power unit costs around 1.5, an a 50 power unit costs around 0.02)

I would like to calculate the cheapest build for a fleet of x amount of power.

At first I though I would get the price of all units, get the average price for 1 power and calculate the most efficient units based of price per power. And this gives me a list sorted from most efficient units, and then I would create a list containing the 30 most efficient PpP (Price per Power) units.

I could then do a check to see if my power of the generated fleet is equal or more than my desired amount, and if not, remove the lest powerful unit, and replace it with the next most efficient bigger one from my list, and repeat until it has enough power in the 30.

The problem is that seeing as the price grows exponentially it means that unit with 1-50 power are always the most efficient.

Does anyone know if there an algorithm that I could use or study?

I want to calculate the cheapest way of achieving a fleet of x amount of power with a maximum of 30 units. without it taking weeks to complete

I have a list of about 30 000 units containing the price and power.

Its a hard problem to explain so apologies if you don't understand anything

EDIT: Sorry I messed up in my description, the price of the units vary, meaning it could be more efficient to get, for example for a 3000 power fleet,  maybe a 15 x 150power units and 15x 50power units fleet is better than 30x 100mp fleet. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: The answer is always going to be a fleet of 30 identical units whose power is at least `x / 30`, and whose cost is minimum. Take the list of 30000 units, and remove all units whose power is less than `x / 30`. Then from the remaining list, find the unit with the lowest cost. Buy 30 of those.

Comment: "The knapsack problem has been studied for more than a century, with early works dating as far back as 1897" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem ;)

Comment: Sorry I updated the thread with a key piece of information, if every unit was the same price then yes this would be the best option, it is my mistake and thank you for the input,


@xerx593 Thank you, This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

To improve the efficiency of your above algorithm you can find the unit whose power is the closest to 30 times the desired power without exceeding it. After that you use the same method removing units one by one and replacing it with the next higher unit. Since 30 of the next higher unit will always exceed the power required, this part of the algorithm only needs to run once.